# Aptana Under linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, opensuse

Hey, I downloaded the Aptanastudio 2.0 and unzipped it in the desktop.

Im trying to run Aptana studio 2.0 under OpenSuse 11 and i get the following error...

Any idea y? Thanks

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=-1
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=/home/avi/Desktop/Aptana Studio 2.0/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.200.v20090520.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher /home/avi/Desktop/Aptana Studio 2.0/AptanaStudio
-name AptanaStudio
--launcher.library /home/avi/Desktop/Aptana Studio 2.0/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.0.200.v20090520/eclipse_1206.so
-startup /home/avi/Desktop/Aptana Studio 2.0/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.200.v20090520.jar
-application com.aptana.ide.desktop.integration.Application
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0/jre/bin/../lib/i386/client/libjvm.so
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=/home/avi/Desktop/Aptana Studio 2.0/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.200.v20090520.jar
```

Comment: Not really enough information here. Try running Aptana from the command line and see if there are any other information dumped to the terminal. You can use pastebin if you need to to paste it all.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the command?

\. AptanaStudio wont open it
Thanks

Comment: Based on the output you posted below, it looks like you are low on memory. How much RAM and swap is in this machine?

Comment: duplicate here http://superuser.com/questions/88518/aptana-under-linux that was migrated from SO (that one should be closed)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Eclipse from your package manager, and installing Aptana as an Eclipse plugin, rather than using the standalone version.

Comment: I did that but eclipse is not running.
Thanks

Comment: If you installed Eclipse from the package manager and it's not working, then perhaps you have other issues?

Answer (score 0):

to run it from the command line open the console and write the following:

```
cd`/home/avi/Desktop/Aptana Studio\ 2\.0/
sudo chmod u+x AptanaStudio
./AptanaStudio
```

So you can see the output (sudo chmod u+x will change the permission of the application, so the user can launch it).

Hope that helps, 
Regards

Comment: If you have "tab completion" enabled, you could just type cd ~/Desktop/Aptana and press the "tab" button, then the sudo chmod thing, and then again ./Aptana and press tab.